# React Native :Dropdown is overlapping with the below content in ios

Tags: react-native

I'm using a dropdown picker in my react native app and its working fine on android devices,but UI breaks on ios

code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import DropdownPicker from '../DropdownPicker';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
export default class RadioButton extends Component {
state = {
value: null,
selectedPicker: null,
picker: 'No Minimum Duration',
itemsA: [
{ label: 'Owner for this place', value: 'opt1' },
{ label: 'France', value: 'france' },
{ label: 'Germany', value: 'germany' }
],
};
onChangeItem = (value, name) => {


}
onselectHandler = (value) => {
this.setState({
selectedPicker: value
})

}
componentDidMount() {



}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {


if (prevState.value !== this.state.value) {
switch (this.state.value) {
case 'No Minimum Duration':
break;
case 'Hour':
this.setState({
itemsA: [
{ label: '1 Hour', value: 1 },
{ label: '2 Hours', value: 2 },
{ label: '3 Hours', value: 3 },
{ label: '4 Hours', value: 4 },
{ label: '5 Hours', value: 5 },
{ label: '6 Hours', value: 6 },
{ label: '7 Hours', value: 7 },
{ label: '8 Hours', value: 8 },
{ label: '9 Hours', value: 9 },
{ label: '10 Hours', value: 10 },
{ label: '12 Hours', value: 12 },

]
})
break;
case 'Day':
this.setState({
itemsA: [
{ label: '1 Day', value: 1 },
{ label: '2 Days', value: 2 },
{ label: '3 Days', value: 3 },
{ label: '4 Days', value: 4 },
{ label: '5 Days', value: 5 },
{ label: '6 Days', value: 6 },
{ label: '7 Days', value: 7 },

]
})
break;
case 'Week':
this.setState({
itemsA: [
{ label: '1 Week', value: 1 },
{ label: '2 Weeks', value: 2 },
{ label: '3 Weeks', value: 3 },
{ label: '4 Weeks', value: 4 },
]
})
break;
case 'Month':
this.setState({
itemsA: [
{ label: '1 month', value: 1 },
{ label: '2 month', value: 2 },
{ label: '3 month', value: 3 },
{ label: '6 month', value: 6 },
]
})
break;
}
}

}

render() {
const { PROP } = this.props;
const { value } = this.state;


return (
<View>
{PROP.map(res => {

return (
<View key={res.key}>

<View style={styles.container}>

<TouchableOpacity
style={[value === res.key ? styles.radioCircleActive : styles.radioCircle]}
onPress={() => {

this.props.setRadioValue(res.key.toLowerCase())
this.setState({
value: res.key,
})

}}>
{value === res.key && <View style={styles.selectedRb} />}
</TouchableOpacity>
<Text style={styles.radioText}>{res.text}</Text>
</View>
{
value === res.key && res.key != 'No Minimum Duration' && !this.props.isHidedrpdwn ?

// <DropdownPicker

// items={this.state.itemsA}
// defaultValue={this.state.itemA}
// onselectHandler={this.onselectHandler}
// onChangeItem={value => this.props.setValue(value.value)}

// name='relation'

// />
<DropDownPicker
items={[
{ label: 'USA', value: 'usa', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" />, hidden: true },
{ label: 'UK', value: 'uk', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" /> },
{ label: 'France', value: 'france', icon: () => <Icon name="flag" size={18} color="#900" /> },
]}
defaultValue={this.state.country}
containerStyle={{ height: 40 }}
style={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
itemStyle={{
justifyContent: 'flex-start'
}}
dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#fafafa' }}
onChangeItem={item => this.setState({
country: item.value
})}
/> : null
}
</View>
);
})}
{/ <Text> Selected: {this.state.value} </Text> /}
</View>
);
}
}
```

[image]

This code is working fine on android but UI breaks on ios,
The screenshot is attached above .This happens on ios only.
the dropdown just get overlapped by content below.How can I fix this issue? .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React native - z-index in dropdown doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900196/react-native-z-index-in-dropdown-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 5):

## I solved this by using height property in containerprops

#### Maybe it could help you too.

```
   <DropDownPicker
                containerProps={{
                  style: {
                    height: this.state.open === true ? 220 : null,
                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                  },
                }}
                schema={{
                  label: "title",
                  value: "status",
                }}
                placeholder="Select status"
                // searchable={true}
                open={this.state.open}
                value={this.state.value}
                items={status_project}
                setOpen={this.setOpen}
                setValue={this.setValue}
                setItems={this.setItems}
                theme="LIGHT"
                listMode="SCROLLVIEW"
                showArrowIcon={true}
                showTickIcon={true}
                TickIconComponent={({style}) =>  <AntDesign
                style={{ marginRight: 5 }}
                color="green"
                name="check"
                size={20}
              />}
              itemSeparator={true}
              itemSeparatorStyle={{
                backgroundColor: "#e5e5e5",
              }} 
              />
```

Comment: I couldn't able to find a solution other than this. Thanks Sayan Dey

Answer (score 4):

the problem is due to the View elements that contain the dropdown, replace them with <></> and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue I fixed it by adding **dropDownDirection="TOP"** props into dropdown component which render dropdown container upside.

```
 <DropdownPicker
 items={this.state.itemsA}
 defaultValue={this.state.itemA}
 onselectHandler={this.onselectHandler}
 onChangeItem={value => this.props.setValue(value.value)}
 name='relation'
 dropDownDirection="TOP"
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

**Possible Solution:**
I couldn't find a way to make the dropdown clickable whether it was `top` or `bottom`, or even with `zIndex`.

In my case, the dropdown wouldn't overlap with the top component, only with the bottom component, and I figured out that the issue was with the `marginTop` inside of `DropDownPicker`. This may work for `dropDownDirection="BOTTOM"` as well. It makes the UI/UX look natural as well.

```
<DropDownPicker
    style={{marginTop: opened ? 175 : 20}}
    ....
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `zIndex:100` property to ios along with `Platform.OS === 'ios'` in the style of the parent view of the picker. Use Platform.OS because the zIndex is not working correct in android and it will cause issues with the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `DropDownPicker` with `View` and set `zIndex` for the wrapper.

```
<View
    style={{ zIndex: 100 }}
>
    <DropDownPicker
        ....
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dropDownDirection="TOP" as follow to open the dropdown upwards.

```
<DropDownPicker
  dropDownDirection="TOP"
  ...
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution for this issue. I'm not sure whether it works on iOS but on Android it worked for me. The solution is:
Wrap each dropdown in a view. Give the top view a large zindex, for instance, 20000. All other views below it must have not a greater zindex value and keep decreasing the zindex property.
e.g For View1 zindex=20000
For View2 zindex=19000
Keep repeating the process